# How to dispute a deleted comment?

Tags: support, comments, deleted-comments

[On a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30013526/608639) I posted a comment which now is deleted.

There's no record of the deletion (other than the comment missing).

How does one dispute a comment deletion? Or get the comment restored?

Comment: Comments are second class citizens on SE sites - as far as we are concerned, their existence is expected to be temporary. Absolutely no point in arguing about them.

Comment: @Oded - comments can helpful in teaching new users to use the site correctly. Some comments are an important part of the Stack Exchange workflow process.

Comment: I can tell you that comments were added reluctantly in the early days. The idea was always that once a post was edit to include important information in comments, the comments were to be deleted. Comments have always been seen this way here.

Comment: I took a look at the deleted comments. They have nothing to do with the question itself, so were rightly deleted.

Comment: You were telling the user where to post their *next* question. Not something about the question itself. Not relevant to that question.

Comment: @Oded - *"You were telling the user where to post their next question"* - thanks, I was not aware that's how it was being read. I corrected that in the updated answer. Thanks again.

Comment: You were being belligerent, is what. We cleaned up the comments, Chris stated clearly the discussion about CR was over, basically stating you should drop it, and you *posted again*. Don't do that again, please.

Comment: @jww your meta commentary you added to the answer is almost longer than the answer itself.  It doesn't belong there.

Comment: @jww I'm not active on CR.SE so I'm not qualified to judge, but ChrisF's comment about CR being for working code seems to be very pertinent.  If the code wasn't working, then why is the answer to the question "go asking this on CR"?

Comment: @ psubsee2003 - that's just it. The code to read a certificate was fine. Hence the code is well suited for CR.SE. But apparently ChrisF and the other lack any expertise in this area, and immediately pegged the code as defective and off-topic for CR.SE. But they sure hammered their opinion on it.

Comment: @jww - I now believe you are wilfully missing my point. The OP posted about something **that wasn't working**. Why this wasn't working is a moot point. The fact that **it wasn't working** makes it off topic for code review. Did I mention that **it wasn't working**?

Comment: @ChrisF - I am not willfully missing anything. The question asked if the use of `i2d_X509` was correct. Then, the the code was provided that reads a certificate and uses `i2d_X509`. The code works fine modulo a memory leak. There's nothing more to the question. As I said a hundred times before: answer the question that was asked, and not the question as you'd like it to be.

Comment: @Oded why was this question migrated? This is a general question.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I asked them to migrate it because in its initial state, it was about a Stack Overflow question; it also has quite a lot of history with other meta discussions around this same question.  Shouldn't be on Meta.SE. It belongs here.

Comment: Thanks @George for commenting. I think the question could fit MSE too, but never mind.

Comment: @Oded As far as I'm concerned, your existence is expected to be temporary.

Comment: The marked answer is wrong by any rational POV. Please unmark it.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You don't. Comments can be deleted without any notice since they are considered "second class citizens".

Everything that is relevant on the long term should come in the question or answer, not in a comment. So move it into the post if it should be kept, if not, leave the comment and don't be surprised it gets deleted one day.

Comment: Ah, I was not aware that sort of advice should be added to the answer. I try to save the answer for technical information, and not policy/procedure information. I usually put policy/procedure in the comments since its not a technical answer. Thanks.

Comment: That shouldn't come in the answer. The answer should be kept on-topic. If it is really commentary, don't mind getting it deleted after a (short) while. In fact what you were don't is putting a 'meta' discussion into the comment.

Comment: Correct. Now this reminds me I have to edit an important comment by a dev into a CM's answer. :)

Comment: A community manager, which is an SE employee dedicated to the community. [Shog](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9) is a CM.

Comment: This is not true by any rational POV. If comments are meant be deleted then why have a vote? If comments are meant to be deleted then why the does the "linked" sidebar reference them. If comments are meant to be deleted why are they not auto-deleted?