# My on topic and useful comments are being deleted

Tags: support, deleted-comments, self-promotion

Yesterday I posted 2 useful, on topic comments to a question and answer, one to each. Today I noticed there were deleted. This morning I left a similar comment and took screenshot just to be sure my memory was not bad.

Here's the screenshot

[image]

The question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66176062/using-mat4-attribute-in-webgl2)

It asks how to use mat4 attributes in WebGL2. I wrote [a full article about that](https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-instanced-drawing.html) and so posted a link. That's a normal thing to do on S.O.  Hundreds of thousands of questions have comments with links to tutorials, documentation, blog posts, as long as they are useful they are on topic

The second link was a link to [an S.O. answer that showed a more flexible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54720138/128511)

Why are these comments being deleted? Is it some automated script? Is it an over zealous mod?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to dispute a deleted comment?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293549/how-to-dispute-a-deleted-comment)

Comment: How are they spam? They're an open source tutorial site, no ads, no asking for contributions, they were written specifically for S.O. because the topics people were asking about were too big for answers. By your logic any link to mdn or msn is spam as well?

Comment: It's not self promotion. my name isn't even on the articles

Comment: Okay fine. Are you saying if I get a friend to leave the exact same comment it won't valid to delete it as spam?

Comment: The comment should stand on its own. Either it's useful or it's not. You're claiming what matters is motivation but the site is about helping people.

Comment: The site is a Q&A site, it's about creating a repository of _questions and answers_. Comments are neither. Your comment is unhelpful for the same reason link only answers are.

Comment: My comment is how the site works. If you're not happy about it you're not obliged to take part. The correct course of action for you was to retrofit the part of the article that was helpful into an _answer_. You chose not to do that, that's your problem

Comment: Be consistent. Comments all over the site show how it works. Here's another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079081/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router) which according to you both comment should have been left as answers and deleted. Here's [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22876978/loop-inside-react-jsx). Needs similar comments deleted.  [Another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31048953/what-do-these-three-dots-in-react-do) just has a link to answer offsite. needs to be deleted.

Comment: You know comments are dealt with by different mods and so may be handled differently, and you know comments are dealt with as and when they're flagged, ergo, not all similar comments will have been deleted. If you have a problem with other users comments, flag them yourself.

Comment: I don't have a problem with those comments. I have a problem with inconsistently enforced rules. According to some answers here a mod can just delete all comments for any reason. They don't like you because they believe your trans. Too bad, comments are okay to delete for any reason. Given your claimed criteria those comments are off topic.

Comment: You have no way of knowing if the comments in question have been flagged, and so they could simply have not been seen. If you flag them and your flags are declined, then come to meta and ask about flag handling consistency, but don't complain about your comments being deleted when you haven't done your due diligence and flagged the comments yourself.

Comment: @gman, if you added the disclosure that you wrote this or that article, couldn't everyone be happy and your comments remain untouched?

Comment: @BoltClock /shrug, it's not like you're a gold badge holder opening it for rep :p, you can provide information nobody else can, I think that's a reasonable reason to reopen. While the dupe answers the general case, it can help to answer the specific case

Comment: @MarcGrue There are two things here. 1. The disclosure, which can easily be fixed to using "my article". 2. Comments seems to be mostly deleted when flagged. No matter the content. No change of phrasing inside the comment can address that.

Comment: @Nick: Huh... somehow I *don't* have a gold [support] badge? I have only been inactive for the last 2 or 3 years.

Comment: @Nick I would go with [What recourse do I have if I believe a moderator has abused their privileges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28867/) ;)

Comment: @rene: Or better yet, the more recent [Is it valid for a diamond moderator to use their powers to override the closing votes of other users, in order to reopen a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404750/is-it-valid-for-a-diamond-moderator-to-use-their-powers-to-override-the-closing)

Comment: @Scratte Okay, but if gman simply deleted the flagged comment then and wrote a new one (and subsequently new ones) with disclosures when linking to own articles - wouldn't that solve the problem?

Comment: @MarcGrue Apparently not. See [this comment by BoltClock](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405172/my-on-topic-and-useful-comments-are-being-deleted?noredirect=1#comment824311_405177). Even if they later say "there's more nuance to it", the comment can just be re-flagged until it's removed. First time as undisclosed affiliation when it's "this article". Next time as plagiarism seeing there's is no evidence that it's theirs if they use "my article". I expect this also applies to links to documentation used in Answers. If I had ever been hired at Oracle, I'd stop posting about f.ex. Java.

Comment: @Scratte So, in the case that you write an un-attributed article (your name is not on it), there's no way to link to it according to SO rules (since plagiarism is assumed)? In the other case of an attributed article, I suppose that you are allowed to link to it if you disclose that you wrote it. Is this correctly understood?

Comment: @MarcGrue I think these rules are not very clear. What if your username just happens to be identical to the author of the site? (I'm not affiliated with scratte.com, but I can't prove that). What if you wrote it, but your Stack username is different? I do not think you can prove or disprove that you authored anything. As far as I can tell it's down to how lucky you get when someone makes a guess as to whether or not it's yours. Can you tell if someone linking to the javadoc wrote that class and also the documentation? Or as this author points out, which page on MDN they did or did not author?

Comment: What comment exactly are you referring to in [ID 11227809](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809) (in [your seventh comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405172/my-on-topic-and-useful-comments-are-being-deleted#comment824279_405172) here)? The [cppreference.com one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-processing-an-unsorted-array#comment87347917_11227809)?

Comment: @Scratte: That's a rather creative interpretation of my comments, I'll give you that. When handling plagiarism, a favorite heuristic us mods use is common sense. We also go through many other steps to determine whether someone actually wrote the work they claim they did, or whether an unquoted/unattributed work was their own words or someone else's. Granted, even after going through all that, we can still get 0.5% of cases wrong, but it's helped us successfully identify many cases that would've otherwise gone unnoticed, as well as successfully give what would've been false positives the clear.

Comment: @Scratte: We'd be happy to address questions about MDN, etc in a separate meta question.

Comment: @BoltClock Your comment got me paranoid about posting anything on this site. What if this author had put the content of the site in a gist? Should they have disclosed authorship? If so, should we remove all links to gists in posts on the site and flag all comments, that does not explicit state authorship? What about links to fiddles?

Answer (score 28):

Even though your name doesn't appear with the article you wrote due to the nature of the site it's published on, it's *really* in your best interest to disclose that you wrote it anyway, just for the sake of transparency. Besides, presumably you're sharing your work because you take pride in it, think it's useful and want others to see it... so it only makes sense to let the reader know you wrote it anyway. So own it!

No need to be formal about it either:

> You might find [this article I wrote](https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-instanced-drawing.html) useful. You might also find [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54720138/128511) useful as an alternative to instancing

And do it sparingly, not that I don't think you already are.

The whole "anything that's promotional in nature and undisclosed is considered spam" thing that Stack Exchange (the Q&A software, and by extension the community) likes to do, the perceived overzealousness of flags, and comments being second-class citizens on a Q&A knowledgebase are all conversations that can be had separately. If you're not regularly posting surreptitious links to content knowing it's really your work, you're not a "spammer". But you've been on the site long enough to understand that we care a lot about disclosure here, and I hope I've shown you how easy it is to stay within what I feel are reasonable guidelines.

Comment: I just realized that disclosing authorship of an article in which your name doesn't appear, if the article isn't in fact yours, is... plagiarism  So, uh... please do this responsibly. And we reserve the right to delete anything we find to be plagiarism. That is all.

Comment: So, if they use "this article" it's a problem. But if they use "my article" it's also a problem?

Comment: Of course there's more nuance to it and it's not just damned if you do, damned if you don't.

Answer (score 14):

As it’s often repeated: comments are second-class citizens. The most likely reason your comments were deleted was that someone flagged them as “no longer needed” and a moderator obliged on the flag. Accusing or implying excess of zeal by a moderator is not productive.

---

Comments' purpose is to address the post they are published under, so the post can be improved or corrected. The comments you mention do not seem to be aligned with that goal. Yes, they link the user to more information (I’ll take your word for it about their relevance; I haven’t followed any of the links), but they do not help to improve the question in any way.

That comment looks more like a (simple and incomplete) answer, or a dupe suggestion

Generally, post information you want to persist as an actual post, like an answer. If you can’t find a way to post it as an answer, you’ll need to be fine with the idea that comments **can and will be deleted when their usefulness regarding the post they are addressing is fulfilled**.

Linking to another post is fine, and in any case the link will remain even when the comment is deleted (in the “linked” section of the sidebar). So nothing was lost in that regard.

The link to your article can be a bit more problematic, **because you are linking to something you are the author of, and you are not disclosing authorship**. If you do this often enough, it’s not unlikely the behaviour will be perceived as “spammish”, and the comments will be flagged more often

Any time you post to something that can be understood as self-promotional, please make sure that you are **disclosing your relationship** with the linked material. And in any case, try not do it very often, since even with disclosure if one were to post posts or comments with self-promotional links very frequently, it can be seen as being excessively self-promotional.

---

But in any case, getting angry at comments deletion is not reasonable or productive. Is better to understand that the main content of the site lives in **posts**, and that comments are there simply as a feature to make posts better and more useful.

If what you wanted was simply to help the OP, the eventual deletion is not an obstacle: the OP is likely to have read the comment and linked material by the time the comment is deleted.

Comment: I am not in a position to "delete all your content", so the comment seems misguided at least. If you are often linking to your own site, articles or/code you are the author of, you should disclose authorship. Please read [this help center article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion), if you haven't read it yet.

Comment: I haven't said you are a spammer. But in this thread in particular, you certainly seem to be more worried about the links than about the posts. I'm sure it's an inaccurate impression, derived from you being angry at the comments or links being deleted, but please do not take it that way. I haven't deleted your comments, nor flagged your posts, nor anything of the like. I'm just trying to help by explaining the rules as I understand them.

Comment: I've been trying the help people with solve their problems. The links help them solve their problems. Deleting them is not helpful to the questioner, nor others, nor the site. They're left as comments precisely because they are just helpful links, not answers. That's a common flag, someone leaves a link answer, gets a comment, "this isn't an answer and should have been left as a comment". I've seen that type of comment many times.

Comment: @gman - You are one hundred percent correct, a link to a website is not an answer, is there a reason you are not simply answering the question?  Is there a reason you are simply replying with a comment, to your own website, instead of providing a high quality answer that can be upvoted?

Answer (score 8):

I've been made aware of this via Meta Stack Exchange (and via Twitter, though that was a link to a personal blog post of yours). I'm a long time user and 2 site mod, and a vaguely experienced user on the site.

I think that there's several issues here, not all of which may be obvious.

Firstly - we've totally failed in explaining the point of comments - they aren't answers 'lite' - they've always meant to be expendable requests for clarification meant to be rolled into a post.

Secondly - that the comment on its own lacks any context. Posts get deleted, websites go down. Considering that our goal (as much as yours) is to build a self contained knowledge base, this can be a problem. In this case without context, it turns clicking on, and accessing the link a hard dependency for your comment to have any use. Even posts on Stack Exchange could in theory be deleted for any number of reasons. Personal sites could be re-organised, or go down. Any one of these turns a formerly 'useful' comment into potential dead weight.

While I realise that you've spent a lot of time and effort building what folks seem to consider the definitive source of information on the subject - and commenting feels a better use of your time (and a way to re-use the knowledge artifacts you have already built) - there's a great reason we suggest people post answers- that it puts what users need in one place, as part of a single, self contained knowledge artifact.

Posting answers also means that the answer is tailored to the particular problem. That and referencing together reinforces the usefulness of the answer to the *specific situation*.

Its also worth considering we have our disclosure rules for a reason - that some folks abuse them. It might not be you but they too would go 'what about fooo?'. I often talk about 'Disclosure is necessary but not sufficient' - simply because shockingly enough, people try to find the edges of the rules, or point out that someone *else* did it.

As a primary, authoritative source - I'd also argue that your disclosure gives *additional* value to your content, simply because *clearly* people seem to recognise the quality and usefulness of your sources.

What I wrote [a little under two years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/331087/135565) on main meta seems relevant here

> As a moderator - the philosophy I follow is *proper disclosure is necessary* but not *sufficient*.
>
> If someone posts something they wrote (or something their employer sells, or is made by a project they're a part of), alongside other posts - their goal here isn't just self promotion. If a user's primary goal is to promote something, rather than take part in Q&A, we have a problem with them.
>
> Further more - a well written answer by a developer familiar with their product, within the guidelines of a site can have a *lot* of value *if* its tailored to the issue at hand. On the other hand "Hey! Use gooboplex! Its awesome" is not.

I also like [this answer by jscs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/182237/135565) that talks about a very similar situation to yours

> First, and **most** importantly, the answers are *always* useful in and of themselves. He includes plenty of text in the body of the answer that solves the problem at hand. The link to the book is included *only* for further reading.

Notice - that I've shared the relevant parts of the answer, and linked back for further context.

Contrast this with a comment that goes

> You might find my [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/331087/135565) here useful. This other answer by [jscs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/182237/135565) also seems very relevant

Or worse

> You would find this [youtube video](https://youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ) useful<sub><sub>1</sub></sub>

I've not actually done anything novel - *but* I've built something self contained, and it'll last even if the original post gets deleted, or Stack Exchange for some inscrutable reason changed its URL schema without fixing things.

<sub><sub>1</sub></sub> <sub>Amusingly that was down for a bit.</sub>

<sub><sub>Which leads to a second point, which is that lots of people don't click on links.</sub></sub>